# error message next to input number not text

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help:
I need to validate that the user is entering a number and not a text in the fuelcost input. Also display an error message in a small, red, italicized font next to the input field and change the focus to the field.(clear the error message after it has been repaired.
I have no clue whatsoever on how to continue from here:

```
<body>
<select id="destList">
  <option id="28">Falmouth to Nantucket</option>
  <option id="11">Falmouth to Edgartown</option>
  <option id="7.6">Falmouth to Oak bluffs</option>
  <option id="38">Falmouth to Newport</option>
</select>
<p/>
<select id="speedList">
  <option id="18" value="14">14 kt</option>
  <option id="24" value="18">18 kt</option>
  <option id="30" value="20">20 kt</option>
  <option id="37" value="22">22 kt</option>
</select>
<p/>
<input type="text" id="fuelCost" value="4.25" />
<p/>
<button onClick="calcCharterCost()">Calculate</button>
</body>

<script>
function calcCharterCost()
{
  var destList = document.getElementById("destList");
  var distance = destList.options[destList.selectedIndex].id;


  var speedList = document.getElementById("speedList");
  var gph = speedList.options[speedList.selectedIndex].id;
  var speed = speedList.value;

  var fuelCost = document.getElementById("fuelCost").value;
  if (fuelCost == "")

  var time;
  time = (distance / speed);

  var cost;
  cost = time * gph * fuelCost;
  alert("cost = " + cost.toFixed(2)); 
}
</script>
```

Help

Comment: I've deleted your "java" question tag, as your question does not appear to have anything to do with this language. If I missed something and did this in error, please let me know.

Comment: _"I need to validate that the user is entering a number and not a text in the fuelcost input"_ `.` character is not a number

Answer (score 0):

`isFinite(variable)`

That handy little function checks if a variable is a number (decimal or integer). You could check in an if statement that if `isFinite(fuelCost)`, calculate the cost. Otherwise, give the user some sort of error message that they didn't enter a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your elements in a form and set the type of your input field to "number". The browser will then handle the error message for you.

```
<input type="number" id="fuelCost" value="4.25"/>
```

Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ca3apsho/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pattern` attribute at `<input>` element with `RegExp` `\d+\.\d+|\d+` to match digit followed by `.` character followed by digit, or digits characters; `<label>` element adjacent to `<input>` element, `css` `:invalid`, `:after`, `content`

```css
:invalid + [for="fuelCost"]:after {
  content:"input requires number";
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fuelCost" value="4.25" pattern="\d+\.\d+|\d+"/>
<label for="fuelCost"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made many changes here. First when you are pulling numbers from the DOM (id's, value's, ect.) they are going to be strings. So when you try to do math using them it will not work. It is best to convert those values to the type that you are looking for. In this case it is number. Another thing is the the option and the input have value attributes. So it may be best to use them.

I changed the HTML to be look like this.

```
<body>
<select id="destList">
  <option id="28" value="28">Falmouth to Nantucket</option>
  <option id="11" value="11">Falmouth to Edgartown</option>
  <option id="76" value="7.6">Falmouth to Oak bluffs</option>
  <option id="38" value="38">Falmouth to Newport</option>
</select>
<p/>
<select id="speedList">
  <option id="18" value="14">14 kt</option>
  <option id="24" value="18">18 kt</option>
  <option id="30" value="20">20 kt</option>
  <option id="37" value="22">22 kt</option>
</select>
<p/>
<input type="text" id="fuelCost" value="" />
<p/>
<button onClick="calcCharterCost()">Calculate</button>
</body>
```

and the JS looks like this.

```
function calcCharterCost()
{
  var time,
      cost,
      errorElem = document.createElement("span"), //create a span for the error message.
      destList = document.getElementById("destList"), //grab the destList ID DOM element.
      speedList = document.getElementById("speedList"), //grab the speedList ID DOM element.
      fuelCost = document.getElementById("fuelCost"), //grab the fuelCost ID DOM element.
      distance = destList.options[destList.selectedIndex].value, //get destList option value.
      gph = speedList.options[speedList.selectedIndex].value, //get speedList option value.
      fuelVal = fuelCost.value, //get the input value.
      distanceNum = Number(distance), // convert the distance variable to a number.
      fuelNum = Number(fuelVal), // convert the fuelVal variable to a number.
      speed = Number(gph), // convert the gph variable to a number.
      parentElem = fuelCost.parentNode; // get the parent node of the input element.

      errorElem.textContent = "Fuel value needs a number value."; // create an error messaeg.


  time = (distanceNum / speed);

  cost = time * speed * fuelNum;

  //ternary operation checks to see if the input is blank and a number type. if it is not append error element.
  fuelVal === "" || typeof fuelVal !== "number" ? parentElem.appendChild(errorElem) : alert("cost = " + cost.toFixed(2)); 
}
```